# IF and ELIF functions and FOR function

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

```
x = int(input("Numbers of Voters:"))
a = input("Candidate 1:")
b = input("Candidate 2:")
c = input("Candidate 3:")

for i in range(x):
    print ("Enter Your 1st choice ")
    for a in range(1):
        a= input("1st Choice: ")
for i in range(x):
    print ("Enter your 2nd choice ")
    for b in range(1):
        b= input("2nd Choice: ")
for i in range(x):
    print ("Enter your 3rd choice ")
    for c in range(1):
        c= input("3rd Choice: ")

if (a > b) and (a > c):
  print("Winner is", a)
elif (b > a) and (b > c):
  print("Winner is", b)
else (c > a) and (c > b):
  print("Winner is", c)
```

My code is not working, its supposed to ask the number of voters, and the name of three candidates, then each voter will have to rank from most to least favorite candidate and when the votes finish, its supposed to print "Winner is" and the one that is the most favorite. I don't know if i have done it correctly because i have a error each time i change it. I am knew to coding in python and i don't know how to make print first choice, second choice and third choice then pass to the second voter so i made to print first choice 3 times then second choice 3 times and third choice 3 times, so if anybody can fix my code i will be very thankful.

Comment: You appear to be using `a`, `b`, and `c` as both the names of the candidates and the accumulated number of votes for each. All you are currently doing is overwriting the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` numerous times.

Comment: `if`, `elif` and `else` are not functions, they are keywords. And they are working as they should, it is the part where you count votes that is broken - add `print(a, b, c)` before your `if` and see for yourself.

Comment: ok im trying now

Comment: i still have a syntax error for line 24 which says else (c > a) and (c > b):

Comment: are you using 1-iteration `for`  loops on purpose? `for i in range(1)` will run exactly one time

Answer (score 0):

I do not know python so I know the below has syntax errors. The logic is what you need to get it to work.

In a nutshell: Have a count for each candidate. Assign a numeric value to each candidate. 3 if they are first choice, 2 if second and 1 if third. In the end, the person with the largest count is the winner.

```
x = int(input("Numbers of Voters:"))
a = input("Candidate 1:")
b = input("Candidate 2:")
c = input("Candidate 3:")

aCount=0
bCount=0
cCount=0

for i in range(x):
    candidate1 = input("First Choice")
    if candidate1 == a :aCount=aCount+3
    if candidate1 == b :bCount=bCount+3
    if candidate1 == c :cCount=cCount+3

   candidate2 = input("Second Choice")
    if candidate2 == a :aCount=aCount+2
    if candidate2 == b :bCount=bCount+2
    if candidate2 == c :cCount=cCount+2

  candidate3 = input("Third Choice")
    if candidate3 == a :aCount=aCount+1
    if candidate3 == b :bCount=bCount+1
    if candidate3 == c :cCount=cCount+1

if candidate1>candidate2 and candidate1>candidate3 : print ("candidate 1 wins")
```

Comment: its not working because of the last line but i dont know why because of IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: I made an edit. Hopefully i got the syntax right. Try it now. Make sure when you try it the first candidate is the winner, so you will see the output